# htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title error on index page - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, html-webpack-plugin

I just deployed my first laravel site to forge/digital ocean.
I am using the default site for the moment.

The index page its blank and inspecting the source this message appears: "We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.", I have javascript enabled, and the rest of the pages load fine, except for the index.

Can anyone help me here?
Many thanks in advance.

Print of the error here:
[error_index_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msWBZ.png)

Its supposed to show the index page, locally works fine, but when deployed the index page is blank.
I have been searching for a solution, with no success.

Comment: webpack? Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @brombeer laravel version 10.10.

Comment: After deploying the files, have you tried running commands like `composer install` or `composer update` and `php artisan optimize`

Comment: @RamChander yes, but the error persisted. I solved it by a fresh install and copy-paste the files to the new project. It probably was old code related to failed installations of tailwind (I suspect).  You are very kind, thank you. = )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by a **fresh install** and `copy-paste` the files to the new project. It probably was old code related to failed installations of `tailwind` (I suspect). Weird, but it worked.